# Java EE - Cannot find ojdbc although it is there

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am getting this error

```
Cannot find class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/datasource-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

Although this > [picture](http://postimg.org/image/9snfomynn/) says something else. I am following a youtube tutorial and guy in the video haven't had any problems with it and everything seems to work fine. I am just learning so I do not really know what else should I post here so if theres something more needed just tell me. I can post some source code, but so far it is just a lot of xml configuration files for spring, tomcat, and maven and simple JSP page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe my answer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442002/java-ee-and-jpa-under-glassfish-noclassdeffound-com-mysql-jdbc-resultsetmetadat/20443198#comment30583569_20443198) can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture only says that you want to instantiate a `OracleDataSource`, but for this to work you have to package your application so that ojdbc is in the classpath at runtime. There are lots of ways to do this depending on your environment. In the simple case of a WAR, you either:

- put `ojdbc.jar` in your servlet container's `lib` directory. In Tomcat 6, that would be `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory, I guess you are using Tomcat by your log window.
- bundle `ojdbc.jar` inside the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your WAR (not really recommended unless you know how to deal with classloader issues/leaks, and considering this question I suppose you don't)

If your application is an EAR, or some standalone application, you will have to find out how your environment organizes its classpath and then put ojdbc.jar somewhere inside of that.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, I got some more errors then but they are not related to this topic so I'll just accept and move along to debugging :D